# Evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(1 + \frac{1}{n^2})}{\ln(n)}$

Tags: limits, logarithms

I need to determine the reason the following limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(1 + \frac{1}{n^2})}{\ln(n)}$$

evaluates to $0$.  Intuitively, I'd say that the numerator gets faster to zero because of the $ n^2$ term but I couldn't prove that rigorously. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The expressions in the title and in the question body are different.

Comment: In any case, the numerator is bounded for $n \to \infty$ and the denominator goes to $\infty$, so ...

Comment: Please change the title to reflect the question in the text, there is some logarithm in the numerator... Please use `\ln` instead of `ln` in math mode. There should be more effort invested in the solution - what about l'Hospital (after replacing $n$ by $x$...) ?!

Comment: This limit is the form $0/\infty$, which is zero.

Comment: @dan_fulea I didn't think ``\ln`` over ``ln`` would be such a dramatic mistake. I should probably have said that the exercise was meant to be solved without BH.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n^2})}{\ln(n)} = \frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(1+\frac{1}{n^2})}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(n)} = \frac{0}{\infty} = 0$$

Comment: Just a reiteration of the comments